# how to set non-standard HttpStatus in Spring reactive's ServerHttpResponse?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, http-status-codes

in **`org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpResponse`** we have the following method :

```
boolean setStatusCode(@Nullable HttpStatus status);
```

that is supposed to allow us to set the http status code for the response. The problem is that we can't use a simple **`int`** value and we have to pass through HttpStatus that cannot resolve non-standard Http status codes (**498** in my case)

Any suggestions on how to set the status otherwise ?

Comment: i have looked around and i havn't seen a way. Maybe this is suitable for an issue at github. All i can think of now is to extend the class and hardcode a status number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After creating an [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/24400) in Github. I was made aware that we can downcast the Interface to `AbstractServerHttpResponse` in order to get access to the `setStatusCodeValue` method that takes an Integer as a parameter and thus enables us to set non-standard statuses.

Also, the Spring team may consider exposing this method in the `ServerHttpResponse` interface for future releases.